# Assign value to specific element in loop jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

How do I assign a value to specific element of a list in jstl

I have to do something like this

```
<c:forEach items="${list.elements}" var="element">
     <c:if test="${element eq 'abc'}">
           <!-- assign a new value to this list element -->
     </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

In java it can be done as

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    if(list.get(i).equals("abc") {
          list.setIndex(i,"def");
     }
}
```

How do we do the same in jstl?